# How can I implememt the following thing using Jquery and PHP

Tags: jquery, html

Suppose I have two anchor tags and two divs with there dynamic id. Example:

```
<a id='a1' href="somepage">A1</a>& <a id='a2' href="somepage">A2</a>
```

and

```
<div id='d1' >Text1 </div> & <div id='d2' >Text2 </div>
```

Initially, all divs are not displayed. But when I press the A1 `<a>` tag then only div1 will be shown & when I press the A2 `<a>` tag then only div2 will show and div1 will not be displayed.

How can I implement this using jQuery and PHP?

Comment: because dynamic id values will come from php...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to give `<a>` and `<div>` something in common. This way if you have a lot of div you won't have to repeat the code over and over again

**For example**

```
<a href='#' class='showdiv' data-div='1'>A1</a>
<a href='#' class='showdiv' data-div='2'>A2</a>
<!-- data-div shows what div the button should show -->

<div class='hidden' id='box1'>one</div>
<div class='hidden' id='box2'>two</div>
```

**And the jQuery**

```
$('.showdiv').click(function(e){
    //e.preventDefault(); //prevent the # from url or any other default
    var divID = $(this).data('div'); //get the id number
    $('.hidden').hide(); // hide all div
    $('#box'+divID).show(); //show the one you selected
});
```

[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/Uvmhc/)

Comment: Thanks brother... I got it, But I don't understand your data-div. will you explain please....

Comment: The data-* attributes are described [here](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes). They allow you to add custom data to any element.

Comment: or [here](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) a little easier explained.

Comment: brother, how can I hide the div if the div is already shown according to the above code..

Comment: I got the solutions... But brother others <a>'s are not working. please help me

Comment: brother others <a>'s are not working in that page even these <a>'s have not any id's.. please help me please

Comment: I mean they are not redirecting to another page even they have href attributes

Comment: See my edited answer, don't use `$('a')` as that is just given as an example and will apply to every `<a>` element instead give it a `class` and use the class.

Comment: Remove `e.preventDefault();` if you want them to redirect to a different page.

Comment: Yes brother I want them to redirect to a different page if they have no id attributes....

Comment: They do not need an `ID` to redirect to another page, they need `href` and then remove `e.preventDefault();` from the script.

Answer (score 2):

As you have dymanmic link and div so you need perfom operation
    on the basis of class

**Html:-**

```
<a id='a1' data-id="1" class="link" href="somepage">A1</a>
<a id='a2' data-id="2" class="link" href="somepage">A2</a>
```

and

```
<div id='d1' class="content_div" >Text1 </div>
<div id='d2' class="content_div">Text2 </div>
```

**Jquery :-**

```
  $('.link').click(function(){
        var id_no = $(this).data('id');
        $('.content_div').hide();
        $('#d'+id_no).show(); 

  });
```

**CSS:-**

```
 .content_div {display :none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $("#d1").hide();
       $("#d2").hide();
$("#a1").click(function () {
       $("#d1").show();
       $("#d2").hide();
});

$("#a2").click(function () {
       $("#d1").hide();
       $("#d2").show();
});
});
```

Comment: thabks, but ids are dyanamic not fixed. because I have thousands of <a> & <div> tag. How can I implement these into a single function? please help me.....

Answer (score 0):

I don`t know if I understand you correctly, is this something what you need:

Html:

```
<a id="display1" href="#">Display 1</a>
<a id="display2" href="#">Display 2</a>
<div style="display: none;" id="div1">1</div>
<div style="display: none;" id="div2">2</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#display1").click(function(){
  $("#div1").show();
  $("#div2").hide();
});

$("#display2").click(function(){
  $("#div2").show();
  $("#div1").hide();
});
```

Fiddle example: [click](http://jsfiddle.net/cJ7Cm/)

Answer (score 0):

Beside Raj's answer you can also work with adding/removing a css-class like 'hideable' where hideable has

`display: none;`

Answer (score 0):

First hide all div on click of any hyper link and show only related on

Like

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#div").hide();
        });

    $("a1").click(function () {
           $("#div").hide();
            $("d1").show();
    });

    $("a2").click(function () {
           $("#div").hide();
           $("d2").show();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible to modify the HTML a little bit you can add onclick events dynamically too:

```
<a class="tablink" id="a1" href="#">A1</a>
<a class="tablink" id="a2" href="#">A2</a>

<div id="a1-div" style="display:none">Text1</div>
<div id="a2-div" style="display:none">Text2</div>
```

And now javascript to add onclick events to all links at once:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tablink").each( function() {
        $(this).click( function() { $("#"+$(this).context.id+"-div").show(); } );
    });
});
```

I've changed `div`'s id's for commodity, and added a common `class` to links.